# Sly JavaScript Library

Tags: jquery, resize, window

I'm trying to work with this library but I not understanding how i can "Reload" the Slider when the size of the windows change.

So what I've done is this:

These is my js script that I load into the page in order to create the Slider.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
'use strict';
(function () {
    var $frame = $('#centered');
    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

    // Call Sly on frame
    $frame.sly({
        horizontal: 1,
        itemNav: 'centered',
        smart: 1,
        activateOn: 'click',
        mouseDragging: 1,
        touchDragging: 1,
        releaseSwing: 1,
        startAt: 7,
        scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
        scrollBy: 1,
        speed: 300,
        elasticBounds: 1,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        dragHandle: 1,
        dynamicHandle: 1,
        clickBar: 1,

        // Buttons
        prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
        next: $wrap.find('.next')
    });
}());

(function () {
    var $frame = $('#smart');
    var $slidee = $frame.children('ul').eq(0);
    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

    // Call Sly on frame
    $frame.sly({
        smart: 1,
        activateOn: 'click',
        mouseDragging: 1,
        touchDragging: 1,
        releaseSwing: 1,
        startAt: 3,
        scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
        scrollBy: 1,
        pagesBar: $wrap.find('.pages'),
        activatePageOn: 'click',
        speed: 300,
        elasticBounds: 1,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        dragHandle: 1,
        dynamicHandle: 1,
        clickBar: 1,

        // Buttons
        forward: $wrap.find('.forward'),
        backward: $wrap.find('.backward'),
        prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
        next: $wrap.find('.next'),
        prevPage: $wrap.find('.prevPage'),
        nextPage: $wrap.find('.nextPage')
    });
}());
});
```

My problem is that i want to change the slider from Horizontal to Vertical when the width of the screen is < 600px.

So I've started with something like these:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 600) 
            $("#centered").attr("id", "smart");
            $frame.sly('reload');
        } else {
            $("#smart").attr("id", "centered");
            $frame.sly('reload');
        }
    });
```

But I cant make it working, and since I'm a newbie with JavaScript/Jquery this makes it even more difficult.

The relative documentation of Sly Library is here: https://github.com/darsain/sly/tree/master/docs

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) 
        $("#centered").attr("id", "smart");
        reload();
    } else {
        $("#smart").attr("id", "centered");
        reload();
    }
});
function reload(){
         var $frame = $('#centered');
var $wrap = $frame.parent();

// Call Sly on frame
$frame.sly({
    horizontal: 1,
    itemNav: 'centered',
    smart: 1,
    activateOn: 'click',
    mouseDragging: 1,
    touchDragging: 1,
    releaseSwing: 1,
    startAt: 7,
    scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
    scrollBy: 1,
    speed: 300,
    elasticBounds: 1,
    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
    dragHandle: 1,
    dynamicHandle: 1,
    clickBar: 1,

    // Buttons
    prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
    next: $wrap.find('.next')
});
}
```

Comment: [link](http://s13.postimg.org/rlottbc07/Screen_Shot_2015_05_11_at_16_55_59.png) I don't get your solution :( In the documentation there is something written something about reloading the Slider but i don't understand it that much ( you can see the linked image ).

Comment: still with your solution even if the width is < 600px the slider keep scrolling horizontally not vertically :(

Comment: then might be error in $frame.sly ({}); check tat properly.
 
Can you please show a jsfiddle or codesnippet? It'd be really helpful. Also, please try to avoid the "wall of code + it doesn't work", you want the readers to understand really easily what is wrong and for that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/owdh1142/2/ This is the jsfiddle code, but its quite different from what I have with that same code locally as you can see from this screen:                       http://s10.postimg.org/btea0mtmx/Screen_Shot_2015_05_11_at_17_53_50.png